# avoid HTTP GET after successful HTTP DELETE done through angular $resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Looking at the developer tools of my browser I noticed my application is doing an unnecessary HTTP GET request after a successful delete operation done through $resource.delete.

On the angular documentation for [resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) I can see
"*Success callback is called with (value, responseHeaders) arguments, where the value is the populated resource instance or collection object. The error callback is called with (httpResponse) argument.*"
so it looks like that is why is doing the request.

My issue, though, is that this happens on successful delete operations, so the GET request always returns an empty 200 OK.

I'd like to avoid having this extra HTTP GET request on successful delete operations; does anybody know how can I achieve this?

I **do** want to use a success callback function, but I don't need the value of the deleted object (in fact there is no value since the HTTP GET returns no content).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, this is how you have implemented your code. Angular doesn't make any GET requests after the DELETE requests until specifically made.

You may want to verify again yourself, else I would request you to show your requests.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: thanks, that's probably what's happening but so far I'm unable to see who/why is generating that request; after seeing the angular documentation I thought that would be it.
I'll simplify my scenario and try to nail this down.